Blazor Render Tree Builder Not Rendering ChildContent
I have tried to find a solution to this issue with no success.
I have created my own text control that wraps MudBlazor's MudText and MudLink controls for rendering text or links to create consistency when managing responsive flows.
Originally, I had a very complex nesting structure in my razor file, and my @ChildContent was rendering correctly. I wanted to simplify it, and use the RenderTree builder to build my control dynamically. When I did builder.AddContent(4,ChildContent), the control rendered, but none of the associated text in the child content came through.
Here's the relevant content in the code behind file:
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

private RenderFragment RenderContent(Typo typo) => builder =>
{
    if (Align.HasValue && _isShowLink)
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<MudText>(0);
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "Align", Align.Value);
        builder.AddContent(2, RenderTextOrComponent(typo));
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }
    else
    {
        builder.AddContent(1, RenderTextOrComponent(typo));
    }
};

private RenderFragment RenderTextOrComponent(Typo typo) => builder =>
{
    var componentType = _isShowLink ? typeof(MudLink) : typeof(MudText);
    builder.OpenComponent(0, componentType);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Class))
    {
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "Class", Class);
    }

    if (_isShowLink)
    {
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "Href", Href);
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "Typo", typo);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Align.HasValue)
        {
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "Align", Align);
        }

        builder.AddAttribute(3, "Typo", typo);
    }

    builder.AddContent(4, ChildContent);
    builder.CloseComponent();
};

From everything I've seen, this should be working. If I include @ChildContent on the razor page, it will render the text included in the child content appropriately.
What am I missing?
Edited to add original razor as requested. I was trying to avoid rewriting the controls several times, when only a couple parameters changed:
@if (IsVisible)
{
    if (Align.HasValue)
    {
        <MudHidden Breakpoint="@Breakpoint.SmAndDown">

            @if (_isShowLink)
            {
                <MudText Align="@Align.Value">
                    <MudLink Class="@Class" Href="@Href" Typo="@Typo">@ChildContent</MudLink>
                </MudText>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudText Align="@Align.Value" Class="@Class" Typo="@Typo">@ChildContent</MudText>
            }

        </MudHidden>
        <MudHidden Breakpoint="@Breakpoint.MdAndUp">

            @if (_isShowLink)
            {
                <MudText Align="@Align.Value">
                    <MudLink Class="@Class" Href="@Href" Typo="@_typoMobile">@ChildContent</MudLink>
                </MudText>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudText Align="@Align.Value" Class="@Class" Typo="@_typoMobile">@ChildContent</MudText>
            }

        </MudHidden>
    }
    else
    {
        <MudHidden Breakpoint="@Breakpoint.SmAndDown">

            @if (_isShowLink)
            {
                <MudLink Class="@Class" Href="@Href" Typo="@Typo">@ChildContent</MudLink>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudText Class="@Class" Typo="@Typo">@ChildContent</MudText>
            }

        </MudHidden>
        <MudHidden Breakpoint="@Breakpoint.MdAndUp">

            @if (_isShowLink)
            {
                <MudLink Class="@Class" Href="@Href" Typo="@_typoMobile">@ChildContent</MudLink>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudText Class="@Class" Typo="@_typoMobile">@ChildContent</MudText>
            }

        </MudHidden>
    }
}

Here's the modified razor
@if (IsVisible)
{
    <MudHidden Breakpoint="@Breakpoint.SmAndDown">
        @RenderContent(Typo)
    </MudHidden>
    <MudHidden Breakpoint="@Breakpoint.MdAndUp">
        @RenderContent(_typoMobile)
    </MudHidden>
}

As mentioned previously, the controls are rendering properly when I view the source. They just aren't including the ChildContent. And when using @ChildContent in the razor page, it displays properly.
Edited to add Minimum Reproducible Code:
I created a new solution that only has MudBlazor and the minimum code to reproduce. It can be found in this GitHub repository.
https://github.com/traseedarkwatch/td-codefragments/tree/main/BlazorRenderTreeChildContent/Sample
The code itself is four files in the Components/Reproduction subfolder

Please don't write your own renderer. Unless you are extremely well versed with it, even Microsoft advices against doing so. If you post the original code that you were trying to simplify, post that and we can see what can be done about it.

In order to become "extremely well versed" you have to use it first, run into problems like this, and try to resolve them. Reaching out to others who are "extremely well versed" to learn from others' experiences as well. ;)
So, even if the razor can be optimized without the RenderTreeBuilder, I'd still like to know why the RenderTreeBuilder isn't workiing, so I can continue to learn. :)

The best way to refactor this is to simply use plain CSS -  this will rid you of the conditionals that render a link and a plaintext - or at least check if you can render MudLink as plaintext. That will get read of the if else that checks for the link. If you dont want to do that for any reason, have the conditional code as a separate *component that has a ChildComponent in it.

There is nothing standing out in your code, so the problem is subltle and probably in a part you didn't post. Set up a [mre] without Mud and as small as possible.

[Polite]  I'll happily tell you what is wrong, but you need to provide a [MRE] as suggested by @HenkHolterman.  At the moment we have bits of the jigsaw, not the full picture.

The minimal reproducable code is in GitHub. I edited and added the link to the GitHub for the reproducable code. The solution can be compiled to demonstrate the results.
